Will derived validators using FluentValidation fail if we include a rule set that doesn't exist?
Suppose I have the following domain models in a C# .NET 6 EF Core project:
public abstract class BaseItem
{
    // Base class implementation...
}

public class FooItem : BaseItem
{
    // Derived Class A implementation...
}

public class BarItem : BaseItem
{
    // Derived Class B implementation...
}

And suppose I am using FluentValidation to validate instances of BaseItem:
public class BaseItemValidator : AbstractValidator<BaseItem>
{
    public BaseItemValidator()
    {
        // Rules for Base Item
    }
}

public class FooItemValidator : AbstractValidator<FooItem>
{
    public FooItemValidator()
    {
        Include(new BaseItemValidator());
        RuleSet("FooRules", () =>
        {
            // Rules for derived FooItem instances
        })
    }
}

public class BarItemValidator : AbstractValidator<BarItem>
{
    public BarItemValidator()
    {
        Include(new BaseItemValidator());
    }
}

If I have a generic service for BaseItem instances using derived validators (dependency-injected), akin to the following..
public class BarItemService<T>
{
    private IValidator<T> _validator;

    public BarItemService(IValidator<T> validator)
    {
        _validator = validator;
    }

    public async Task AddItem(T item, CancellationToken token = default)
    {
        var result = await _validator.ValidateAsync(item, opt => opt.IncludeRuleSets("FooRules"), token);
        if (!result.IsValid)
        {
            // Indicate the item is not valid
        }

        // Rest of the method...
    }
}

..will the validator fail if T is BarItem and we try to include the rule set specific to FooItem?

Is the real question what happens if you use opt.IncludeRuleSets(...) with an unrelated type? FooItem and BarItem have no inheritance relation. Neither do FooItemValidator and BarItemValidator. You'll get a runtime cast error at some point

..will the validator fail if T is BarItem and we try to include the rule set specific to FooItem? question sounds like you could have simply tested it, or? maybe I have misunderstood it
